# Xamarin.Forms > List > Custom Renderer

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer

Is it possible to write a custom renderer for the Xamarin.Forms List, that renders two rows next to each other, so basically like a bound grid view

```
-------------
Item1 | Item2
-----------
Item3 | Item4
-------------
Item5 ...
```

Thanks, Nikolai

Comment: Try the free grid component : https://components.xamarin.com/view/devexpress-grid ; https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Xamarin/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom renderers in Xamarin.Forms. You can use the GridView component in [Xamarin Forms XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs).  Setting MaxColumns as 2 will render 2 columns in a row

```
<ctrl:GridView 
 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  x:Name="GrdView" RowSpacing="5"
  ColumnSpacing="5" MaxColumns="2"
  TileHeight="120"
   CommandParameter="{Binding}"
   Command="{Binding StartTaskCommand}"
   IsClippedToBounds="False">
  </ctrl:GridView>
```

[Here is a tutorial on how to use that](https://chaseflorell.github.io/xamarin/2015/03/14/xamarinforms-gridview/).

Comment: Hi Sreeraj, do you have a working project with dummy data somewhere? I am missing something in my implementation and really try to get your solution to work. Like it!!!